# Issue With Event Handlers From Loaded Data

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener, innerhtml

So, I am having some trouble working with event handlers when interacting after a .load(); function executed.

On page, when a radio button is clicked, the callback loads the inner-page/data, no problem. However, when I try to use an on.(click) event from the inner elements, the function fails. All the code is at top level. Any idea why the event is failing?

```
$('#radical input[type=radio]').on('click', function() { $('.subradical').load('../page');
});
```

This works fine, it loads the data in-page beautifully.

```
$('#radical .subradical li').on('click', function() {
var one = $(this).attr('id');
var two = $(this).attr('pic');
var three = $(this).attr('title');
$('#radical .display').css('background:url(../imgs/'+two+'); background-size:cover');
$('#radical .display .title').text(three);

});
```

This does not work.

To explain: "radical" is at top level. 
"subradical" is empty and where the loaded data (php) displays.
The event of clicking the li from the loaded data in "subradical" should trigger grabbing the attrs and dropping them into the "radical" display elements, but it is not. Anything I am not seeing here?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Curiously, when I execute this function:

```
$('#radical .subradical').on('click', function(e) {
alert('this works');});
```

The alert shows. However, when I add the LI it fails.

```
$('#radical .subradical li').on('click', function(e) {
alert('this does not work');});
```

Comment: What is in the browser's developer tools console when you run this page?

Comment: Hi Karl. Not seeing any errors. Using Chrome on Win10.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think it's probably because the on("click", function(){}) with two operands only applies to objects which exist at the time it is called, not those created (in your case loaded) later. I think you need to use the three-parameter form of the on function and call it on something which does exist, as in

```
$("#existing-container").on("click", ".selector-for-something-created-later",
   function(e){ 
     dosomething(); 
   });
```

Comment: Frankie, at your suggestion, I added the 3rd leg and it seems to work perfectly. Cheers and thank you. Voted up.